# Limit of consecutive Lp norms

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I've been wrestling with the following proof off and on for a number of days, and I'm in need of a nudge in the right direction.

Let $(E,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space with $0 < \mu(E) < \infty$. Consider $f \in L^\infty(E)$ with $\|f\|_\infty > 0$; show that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \|f||_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}}{\|f\|_n^n} = \|f\|_\infty $$

Now I'm familiar with the result and proof that under these circumstances $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|f||_n =  \|f\|_\infty$, so I've been focusing on somehow showing the two limits to be the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this (or nearly this) was asked and answered on this site before, but haven't found it.

Comment: I looked, but couldn't find anything quite the same...

Comment: Ah, here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/92147/ (See Did's answer.)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

From Holder's inequality, $$\|f\|_n^n=\int_E|f|^n\leq\left(\int_E|f|^{n\frac{n+1}{n}}\right)^\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\int_E1\right)^\frac{1}{n+1}=\|f\|_{n+1}^n\mu(E)^\frac{1}{n+1}\Rightarrow \frac{\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}}{\|f\|_n^n}\geq \|f\|_{n+1}\mu(E)^{-\frac{1}{n+1}},$$ and also $$\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}=\int_E|f|^{n+1}\leq\|f\|_{\infty}\int_E|f|^n=\|f\|_{\infty}\|f\|_n^n\Rightarrow \frac{\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}}{\|f\|_n^n}\leq \|f\|_{\infty}.$$

Now, let $n\to\infty$.