# ODE system and show infinite number of positively invariant ellipsoids

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions, set-invariance

The system of ODEs is:
$$
\dot{x} = -2x+yz \\
\dot{y} = x-xz \\
\dot{z} = xy
$$

I found two lines of equilibria etc. but I now need to find the parameters for this "energy" or Lyapunov function, so as to construct a bounding ellipsoid I suppose. If it has finite size then I am thinking it contains an infinite number of orbits that either entering it, or were there, but never leave ($\frac{dL}{dt}=0$).

$L(x,y,z) = ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2$

I differentiated this and set to zero, to create a `shell' where the Lyapunov function is constant on (like energy), and came up with,

$$
2xyz(a-b+c) + 2bxy-4ax^2 = 0,
$$
which to get rid of the first term I set $a=b-c$, leaving,

$$
2bxy=4(b+c)x^2.
$$

Unfortunately, I still have a term $xy$, and do not see how to get it into the form of the ellipsoid. Is this the right method? I don't think completing any squares will help either.... In the end I am supposed to add a cubic term to the RHS $(\dot{x}_i = \cdots - x_i^3)$ and then show the origin is globally asymptotically stable, if that helps anyone understand the type of question.

Comment: Still not interested in cleaning the mess [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/92147/)? Why?

Comment: How does one send you an email in private?

Comment: One does not. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the derivative of your Lyapunov function to be always $\le 0$, you'd need $b=0$ as well (because $xy$ is sometimes positive and sometimes negative).
And it's $a = b - c$, not $a = b + c$.  You'll get hyperbolic cylinders, not ellipsoids.  The origin is **not** asymptotically stable for this system (before you add the cubic term), because of those lines of equilibria.

Comment: Yes, I see my mistake ($a=b-c$). So I was thinking of ellipsoids but this definitely makes it have only two - $x$ and $z$. As far as its form, it is barely a hyperbolic cylinder and more of an "X" :)