# Measures and $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am styding a bit of $\mathcal{L}_p$ spaces and, in particular, where $p=\infty$ and it is already clear to me that $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty} \|f\|_p = \|f\|_\infty$, but I've met with the following exercise, that I could not prove:

> Let $\mu$ be a finite measure in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function with $0<\|f\|_\infty<\infty$. Then, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_\Omega |f|^{n+1}d\mu}{\int_\Omega |f|^n d\mu} = \|f\|_\infty$

Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Use Dominated convergence theorem to get the limit into the integrals and then simplify

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \|f\|_{\infty}$ for $f \in L^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92147/show-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fraca-n1a-n-f-infty-for-f) (but note that the accepted answer is not correct)